# jQuery-ui not loading or tabs don't pull other contents down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm developing a wordpress website and I'm having issues with the jQuery-ui tabs.

First of all, sometimes jQuery doesn't load and I have no idea why this happens, I suppose it's some kind of compatibility issue. The tabs appear completelly unformated with the tabs' contents on top of the rest.

Then, about the tabs, they are in vertical fashion, not as they are presented by default.
The tabs' contents are dynamic, and the only thing I know is the min-height. However, when I open a content which has a larger height, it doesn't pull the rest of the website down, it stays on top or below the other contents. I hope you can understand what I mean.

I will leave here the URL to the website, you can see the green tabs near the bottom. However, I can only leave the site "open" for public access for a somewhat short period of time, or the client will be upset.

[Link to website](http://www.vinetowinecircle.com/castas_post/graciano-es-tinta-miuda-pt/)

If you click on "Caract. Molecular (OIV)" or "Fenologia" you will see everything looks good. But if you click on "Potencial Vegetativo" (I placed some lorem ipsum), you will see what's wrong -> the contents stay on top of other contents (the phrase "Voltar ao resultado da pesquisa") and below the footer.

The website is only being developed in portuguese at the moment, and I apologize for that. However, I believe you will be able to understand the HTML/CSS markup anyway. Thanks in advance for all your help.

EDIT: By the way, the site is only optimized for Firefox, at the moment. Cheers.

Comment: are you including jquery-ui.css?

Comment: Yes, of course. And also the theme CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your source, you are including jQuery from the google repository, then jQuery UI and then local jQuery again. JQuery is built into WordPress so that plugins can utilize it without having to guess at wither or not it is loaded. You should be enquing the javascript properly so that it gets loaded in the correct order.

If you want to use the google repository version of jQuery, you should be doing something like this:

```
<?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }    

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

To load an additonal script that is depenant on jQuery, you use something like this:

```
<?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'newscript',
        plugins_url('/js/newscript.js', __FILE__),
            array('jquery')
    );
    }    

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```